# Why is integrating over a single point is "defined" to be zero, rather than proved?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

Now that I'm studying calculus from Spivak, I found it stated that $\int_{a}^{a} f(x) dx$ is **defined** to be zero.

Although this makes sense if the integral is thought of as the area, can't this result be **derived** instead as a **logical consequence** from the definition of the integral?

**Edit**

I asked this question exactly as integrating over a single point being equal to zero was assumed to prove the relation mentioned in [Plop's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4810041/573453). so I was just curious if BOTH statements can be proved without the need of taking one as an axiom or a definition

Comment: The original defintion of Riemann integral is for the case$\int_a^b$ where $a<b$.  Then we add definitions for cases $a=b$ and $a>b$ in such a way that the formula $\int_a^c = \int_a^b+\int_b^c$ still holds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 3 or 4 ways to look at it :

(1) What user "gnasher729" says : It is the gradual evolution of Statements.
In other words , it comes from "... Direct Consequence of the Definition of Integration is that $\int_a^af(x)dx$ is always $0$ ..."  via "... Definition of Integration indicates that $\int_a^af(x)dx$ is $0$ ..." which then gives "... Definition of Integration is that $\int_a^af(x)dx$ is $0$ ..." which will end up like "... Definition of $\int_a^af(x)dx$ is $0$ ..."

(2A) What user "PLOP" says regarding Intervals : It comes from Intervals $[a,b]+[b,c]=[a,c]$
We can then set $a=b$ to get that the Integral over $[a,a]$ is $0$.
[[ this is what I too would have given , if PLOP had no given it earlier ]]

(2B) What user "PLOP" says regarding Area : There is $0$ Area due to Interval $[a,a]$
Here , no matter what finite value $f(a)$ is , the Area is always $f(a) \times 0 = 0$.
[[ this is what I too would have given , if PLOP had no given it earlier ]]

IMPORTANT : When $f(a)$ is infinite , we will have other issues consider !

**(3) We can show it by Proof too : I think this "logical consequence" is what OP is looking for.

Let $F(x)$ have the Derivative $f(x)$

Then we will have :

$$\int_a^af(x)dx=F(x)|_a^a=F(a)-F(a)=0$$

This is the Shortest Proof , without using some other lemma or theorem.**

(4) We can have other ways too , but I think these are enough !
It is Consistent & All ways will be somewhat "Equivalent" , when we analyze it.

Answer (score 1):

It may depend from the definition of the integral. But if the relation $\forall a,b,c, \quad \int^c_a = \int^b_a + \int^c_b$ has been proved beforehand or is assumed in an axiomatic framework, then the property that you are talking about follows straightforwardly.

On the other hand, if the integral is defined as     the area under the curve (whatever this means), then the area under the curve does not change if we change the value of the function at finitely-many points (this is a basic property that we expect from a correct notion of « area »). So, the integral of a point does not change if we change the value of the function at the only one point. So $\int^a_a f(x) = \int^a_a \frac{f(x)}{2} dx = 2\int^a_a f(x)dx$.

Comment: I asked this question exactly as integrating over a single point being equal to zero was assumed to prove the relation you stated. so I was just curious if BOTH statements can be proved without the need of taking one as an axiom or a definition

Comment: I edited my answer.

Answer (score 1):

It is quite possible that it is so obvious from the definition of an integral that the integral over a single point is zero, that someone would say it is zero by definition.

The sentence may have evolved. From “it is obvious from the definition of an integral that the integral over a single point is zero”, to “by the duo fan integral, the integral over a single point is zero” to “the integral over a single point is by definition zero”.